# Webpack bundles devDependencies instead of peerDependencies when using yarn link

Tags: npm, webpack, dependencies, yarnpkg

I'm having some trouble with how `yarn link` works in conjunction with webpack. I'm developing a components library that I'm using in a different application. For development I want to use `yarn link` to see my components working in my application.

In my components library I have `react` in `peerDependencies` **and** `devDependencies` because I need `react` for running tests for instance.

Now when I bundle my application `react` is bundled twice because webpack resolves `react` in my components library to its own `node_modules` instead of the application I'm using it in. This results in a react error saying that react is available twice.

How can I make sure webpack only bundles react once when using `yarn link`?

Comment: Is your component library also using Webpack?

Comment: @JoeClay yes, it does.

Comment: Okay, follow up question - does your component library's Webpack config define it as being a library, and does it specify that React should be an `external`?

Comment: @JoeClay It's simply a bundler and dev server for the development application.